# Convert JDBC fetched Date data as XML into Date object

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jdbc, ready-api

I am using Ready API and I was wondering how to convert a date value that is fetched from Oracle SQL Database from a JDBC connection which is stored in an XML Holder inside a Script Assertion and then using the same to assert with a timestamp value fetched from an API Response.

Ex;
The Value obtained from the Database looks like

```
2015-7-8 17:40:44. 715000000
```

And the date from the API Response looks like

```
1436377244715
```

Question is how do I convert the Date got from the Database or from the Response to make it assertible

Comment: what you want then? what is the question?

Comment: Edited..pls see again

Comment: if i can understand your date is of type String no?

Comment: Yes and its not working

Comment: ok then check my answer

Comment: The converted time comes out like 2015-07-08 13:40:44. 715000000

Comment: Its not asserting the same even though the values are same

Comment: check my edit now, you have to use `yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss. SSS00000` instead

Comment: It says unparseable date : "2015-7-8 17:40:44. 715000000"

Comment: of course this work this is unparseable date because it is not double, it contain character what did you want to do exactly @subby?

Comment: As i already mentioned in the Question i want to assert these two values

Comment: you want to compare if the two dates are equal or not?

Comment: Now using the same formatter pattern for both gives me the value Mon 2015-07-17 00:17:24. 000 for 2015-7-8 17:40:44. 715000000

Comment: you want to compare if the two dates are equal or not?  - **Yes**

Comment: check my edit above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your date `1436377244715` date then you can use :

```
Date d = new Date(Long.parseLong("1436377244715"));
```

The second you can get your Date fro; `2015-7-8 17:40:44. 715000000` like this :

```
String str = "2015-7-8 17:40:44. 715000000";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. SSS");

Date date = format.parse(str);
System.out.println(date);
```

So to compare the two dates you can use :

```
//convert the date from the API Response
Date date1 = new Date(Long.parseLong("1436377244715"));

//convert the date obtains from DATABASE
String str = "2015-7-8 17:40:44. 715000000";
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss. SSS");
Date date2 = format2.parse(str);

System.out.println(date1);
System.out.println(date2);

//check if the two dates are equal or not
if (date1.equals(date2)) {
    System.out.println("CORRECT");
} else {
    System.out.println("NOT CORRECT");
}
```

This will gives you :

```
Wed Jul 08 18:40:44 WAT 2015
Fri Jul 17 00:17:24 WAT 2015
NOT CORRECT
```

Comment: Thank you but in reality the values that i provided in my question are equal after conversion. So why are they not getting parsed properly? I mean i need to make it comparable which means positive assertions

Comment: If you want to cross cheeck you could use this site https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: @subby `1436377244715 ===== 2015-7-8 18:40:44. 715` and not `2015-7-8 17:40:44. 715` so check you are using the correct dates

Comment: But when i use the above site, it shows me the one that I provided

Comment: The timezone must be GMT..if it helps

Comment: can i see what dates you try @subby

Comment: Here are some sample dates where the left ones are fetched from the Database and the right ones(timestamps) are from the Response of the API

Comment: 2015-7-8 17:40:44. 715000000 -------> 1436377244715 |        
          2015-7-31 15:10:8. 858358000 -------> 1438355408858 |
          2016-8-18 14:24:21. 307701000 ------> 1471530261307

Comment: I want to convert them to validate them as equal